# FIR as a synonym

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

At the moment, we have tag [infinite-impulse-response](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-impulse-response) with synonym [iir](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iir).

We also have tags [finite-impulse-response](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-impulse-response) and [fir](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fir). However, the latter is not a synonym for the former. I believe it should be. The tag name would be self-descriptive, and the tag would be easy to find via its popular acronym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done!  I also swapped the <kbd>stft</kbd> tag with its longer counterpart to go with this way of doing things.

[image: Screen shot of tag addition]